# IGNORE_DUP_KEY in Sql Server 2000 with composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table, composite

I'm trying to create a table in SQL Server 2000, that has a composite primary key with IGNORE_DUP_KEY set to ON.

I've tried looking for this option in SQL Server Management Studio Express but I couldn't find it so now I'm down to creating the table programatically. Every SQL command I found on Google or Stack Overflow gives me an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '('.

The table should have 4 columns (A,B,C,D) all decimal(18) and I need the primary key on A,B,C.

I would appreciate if someone could post an example CREATE command.

Comment: what is the meaning of a primary key with ignore_dup_key?? It looks like a design flaw!

Comment: I was expecting for this comment :), but I don't think it's a design flaw as long as you take all aspects(the good and the bad) into consideration -> this is what will work for me right now. I want my items to be unique, but I don't want to verify their uniqueness during the insert. I've seen that it can be done manually using joins but I doubt that it is as fast as using IGNORE_DUP_KEY. If you want, I can describe more where I will be using this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create table MyTable2 (
  [a] decimal(18,2) not null,
  [b] decimal(18,2) not null,
  [c] decimal(18,2) not null,
  [d] decimal(18,2),
  CONSTRAINT myPK PRIMARY KEY (a,b,c)
)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX MyUniqueIgnoringDups
ON MyTable2 (a,b,c)
    WITH IGNORE_DUP_KEY       --SQL 2000 syntax
  --WITH(IGNORE_DUP_KEY = On) --SQL 2005+ syntax

--insert some data to test.
insert into mytable2 (a,b,c,d) values (1,2,3,4);--succeeds; inserts properly
insert into mytable2 (a,b,c,d) values (1,2,3,5);--insert fails, no err is raised.
-- "Duplicate key was ignored.   (0 row(s) affected)"
```

For anyone interested, here's an explanation of what's happening from [Erland Sommarskog on the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/0a2a1560-562a-4222-9a4d-83e5945bb1a5):

> When `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` is OFF, a duplicate key value causes an error and the entire statement is rolled back. That is, if the statement attempted to insert multiple rows, no rows are inserted.
>
> When `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` is ON, a duplicate key value is simply ignored. The statement completes successfully and any other rows are inserted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it says `'IGNORE_DUP_KEY' is not a recognized ALTER TABLE option.`. Any ideas?

Comment: Perfect. It's working. Thank you!. However, in the link you provided I found an interesting link related to the performance&compatibility problems. They are ok for me, but if someone else uses this, then you should check out that link.

Comment: Yes, I've seen :). Actually, having 2 separate commands, allowed me to run the CREATE INDEX on my already created table. Anyway, I though accepting the solution was enough :)